# Reading each word from Email addresses in Java

Tags: java

I have an email address as a `String` and from that I have to find certain words if Email is containing. I have to find the words before, after and, in between based on these:-

**. , @ , - , _**  .

My Code:

```
String s = "asdfgabc@gmail.com";
String var = null;
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    var+=c;
    if(var.contains("@") || var.contains(".") || var.contains("-") || var.contains("_") ){
        //System.out.println(var);
    }
    else{
        var+=c;
        System.out.println(var);
    }
}
```

Comment: Examples, expected output, et cetera.

Comment: @RajeevArora: You are the one who asks for help, so you should put some effort to your question so that others can focus on solving the problem and not on guessing what the OP actually asks for.

Comment: He's saying that he wants to split up the email into seperate words without symbols. I don't think it's that hard to understand. But I do agree that he could have been a bit kinder in the comments. But also Danstahr and others could have been kinder too, so it kinda goes all around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply split the string and then process your words :

```
String[] words = "bad.guy@nowhere.net".split("[._@-]");
Arrays.println(words);
// >> [bad, guy, nowhere, net]
// Process the output word by word
```